# How to iterate a variable length tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to build a graph to accept variable size images. So after the last conv layer, I want to iterate through every pixel and feed that vector to softmax layer. And then calculate the mean of them.

It may look like this:

```
last_max_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(...)

output = tf.reshape(last_max_pool, [batch_size, None, channels])

results = []
for one_batch in output:
    result = []
    for pixel in one_batch:
        result.append(tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(pixel, W_sf) + B_sf))
    result = tf.reduce_mean(result)
    results.append(result)
```

But how to build the graph like this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need for loop, instead you can reshape `last_max_pool` to `[None, channels]`

```
output = tf.reshape(last_max_pool, [None, channels])
softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(output, W_sf) + B_sf)
final_output = tf.reduce_mean(results)
```

Comment: But I need to calculate for each sample. In other words, I need to iterate `batch_size`.

Comment: I realized that I made a mistake on code, now I fix it. Sorry.